# is it possible to give time limit to dialog box

Tags: android

I am displaying String in dialog box instead of using Toast message. I want to give time limit in order to show the dialog box for certain Time limited. i am not sure how to do this in android. if there is a possible to give time limit to dialog box, pls guide me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Customize the dialog using [this tutorial](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-dialog-example).
2. Then remove that button in XML
3. Then add a handler -- [this link](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html) -- and close the dialog after a certain duration.